# Getting Python to Print the Hour of Day

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I am using the following code to get the time:

```
import time

time = time.asctime()

print(time)
```

I end up with the following result:

```
'Tue Feb 25 12:09:09 2014'
```

How can I get Python to print just the hour?

Comment: You can look at the docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html. I agree that 'time' is quite an old-fashioned library, which is not so much object-oriented

Comment: You shouldn't use 'time' as a variable name: in that way you're replacing the library 'time' with your variable 'time'

Answer (score 43):

You can use [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime):

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> dt.datetime.now().hour
9
```

Or, rather than now() you can use today():

```
>>> dt.datetime.today().hour
9
```

Then insert into any string desired:

```
>>> print('The hour is {} o\'clock'.format(dt.datetime.today().hour))
The hour is 9 o'clock
```

Note that `datetime.today()` and `datetime.now()` are both using your computer's notion of local time zone (ie, a 'naive' datetime object).

If you want to use time zone info, it is not so trivial. You can either be on Python 3.2+ and use datetime.timezone or use the third party [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net). I am assuming your computer's timezone is fine, and a naive (non time zone datetime object) is fairly easy to use.

Comment: Hands down the best answer as it avoids the use of the underwhelming `time` module.

Answer (score 11):

```
import time
print (time.strftime("%H"))
```

Answer (score 7):

[`time.asctime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.asctime) will create a string, so extracting the hours part is hard. Instead, get a proper [`time.struct_time`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time) object, which exposes the components directly:

```
t = time.localtime() # gives you an actual struct_time object
h = t.tm_hour # gives you the hour part as an integer
print(h)
```

You can do it in one step if that's all you need the hour for:

```
print(time.localtime().tm_hour)
```